# Increasing block size decreases performance

Tags: cuda

In my cuda code if I increase the blocksizeX ,blocksizeY it actually is taking more time .[Therefore I run it at 1x1]Also a chunk of my execution time ( for eg  7 out of 9 s ) is taken by just the call to the kernel .Infact I am quite amazed that even if I comment out the entire kernel the time is almost same.Any suggestions where and how to optimize?

P.S.      I have edited this post with my actual code .I am downsampling an image so every 4 neighoring pixels (so for eg 1,2 from row 1 and 1,2 from row 2) give an output pixel.I get a effective bw of .5GB/s compared to theoretical maximum of 86.4 GB/s.The time I use is the difference in calling the kernel with instructions and calling an empty kernel.
It looks pretty bad to me right now but I cant figure out what am I doing wrong.

```
 __global__ void streamkernel(int *r_d,int *g_d,int *b_d,int height ,int width,int *f_r,int *f_g,int *f_b){


    int id=blockIdx.x * blockDim.x*blockDim.y+ threadIdx.y*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x+blockIdx.y*gridDim.x*blockDim.x*blockDim.y;
    int number=2*(id%(width/2))+(id/(width/2))*width*2;

     if (id<height*width/4)
    {

        f_r[id]=(r_d[number]+r_d[number+1];+r_d[number+width];+r_d[number+width+1];)/4;                              
        f_g[id]=(g_d[number]+g_d[number+1]+g_d[number+width]+g_d[number+width+1])/4;             
        f_b[id]=(g_d[number]+g_d[number+1]+g_d[number+width]+g_d[number+width+1];)/4;  
    }


  }
```

Comment: thanks ! but i did google and do some homework before posting it on stack overflow.

Comment: @Nick: [LMGTFY URLs aren't allowed for a reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links). You'd know that if you hadn't tried to obfuscate it with tinyurl, which is *also* strongly discouraged. I like knowing where I'm being linked to.

Comment: @Manish - I want to help you, but you haven't selected a correct answer on the previous two questions you asked about cuda. It will help if you give us more incentive.

Comment: @Manish - Also 7s is far far far too long.

Comment: @Manish - And lastly, you need to profile your code. It will be worth your time and others time to get the profiler working.

Comment: @jmilloy:Thanks for the interest.I selected answer in previous one.I too want to use the profiler .i just cant get it to work.I had posted a question about it .appreciate it if you can help me with that one.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking up the matrix multiplication example in CUDA SDK examples for how to use shared memory.

The problem with your current kernel is that it's doing 4 global memory reads and 1 global memory write for each 3 additions and 1 division. Each global memory access costs roughly 400 cycles. This means you're spending the vast majority of time doing memory access (what GPUs are bad at) rather than compute (what GPUs are good at).

Shared memory in effect allows you to cache this so that amortized, you get roughly 1 read and 1 write at each pixel for 3 additions and 1 division. That is still not doing so great on the CGMA ratio (compute to global memory access ratio, the holy grail of GPU computing).

Overall, I think for a simple kernel like this, a CPU implementation is likely going to be faster given the overhead of transferring data across the PCI-E bus.

Comment: Yeah CPU implementation might be better but I need to do this for gigapixel images .This is why we have to use GPUs.Do you have any advice on doing this in a better way?

Comment: Take a look at imageDenoising_nlm2_kernel.cu inside the CUDA SDK imageDenoising sample. The kernel shows you how to use shared memory. That should speed up your processing considerably. You may also want to look into texture memory. Also, for the id, you may want to say something like int ix = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x; int iy = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y; int idx = ix + iy * width; or something like that. It looks cleaner and can make sure you don't have indexing conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting the fact that one multiprocessor can execute up to 8 blocks simultaneously and the maximum performance is reached exactly then. However there are many factors that limit the number of blocks that can exist in parallel (incomplete list):

- Maximum amount of shared memory per multiprocessor limits the number of blocks if #blocks * shared memory per block would be > total shared memory.
- Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor limits the number of blocks if #blocks * #threads / block would be > max total #threads.
- ...

You should try to find a kernel execution configuration that causes exactly 8 blocks to be run on one multiprocessor. This will almost always yield the highest performance even if the occupancy is =/= 1.0! From this point on you can try to iteratively make changes that reduce the number of executed blocks per MP, but therefore increase the occupancy of your kernel and see if the performance increases.

The [nvidia occupancy calculator(excel sheet)](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls) will be of great help.

Comment: This general advise addresses the observation you stated in your question. For more specific performance optimizations you must provide us with more specific information about your code.